# Xamarin Forms WebView Does not display

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display a web page in my xamarin forms app using `WebView`

below is my code

```
<Label Text="test" />
<WebView Source="https://www.ezyhaul.com/my/carrier-web-announcement/"
         HeightRequest="1000"
         WidthRequest="1000" />
```

but this is not loading on Android device, any special requirements i need to add?

Comment: Is your webview contained in StackLayout or RelativeLayout ?And you could try to change a url to see if it display.

Comment: it is on Stacklayout and i tried with another link not working

Comment: That's weird. I've created a demo here that doesn't have any other Settings to load the page，it works.Maybe you could try creating a custom renderer to load it..

Comment: any suggestion about creating custom renderer?

Comment: you could refer to [custom renderer webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)

Comment: In my case the loading of the page took ages (for whatever reason) ...